# How to do one-hot encoding in the serving data in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, production

Here I am talking about problems I encountered while trying to put machine learning models into production.

I have labeled data split into train and test data after feature engineering (including one-hot encoding) and optimized a model based on that. The serving data will come in real time and experience the same feature engineering. Then the model will be used for predicting the label of the serving data.

The question is the categorical features in the serving data contains different categories compared to the train and test data. Therefore, one-hot encoding will results in different number of features, rendering the model not usable.

I did some research online and it seems a general solution is to use

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(X_train)
```

and then use

```
enc.transform(X_test)
```

This will work totally find if I am in the experimental stage. However, in production mode, my train/test module (or code) and serving module (or code) are
in different files/places. So how should I pass this `enc` value from the train/test module to the serving module? Do I save it as json or pickle files first in the train/test stage and then upload and use it in the serving stage? Or there is a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: The way that I personally addressed this issue was to create a metadata class which stored all of the model information (excluding weights and the optimizer state) required for inference. For my case it was mainly to keep track of the encoded categorical values when generating deep embeddings, however I also saved the state of my SKLearn scaler (which you can equivalently do for your `OneHotEncoder`).

Edit: I should mention that I saved the metadata dict as json and used the class to handle both the model and it's metadata.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz, why not make it an answer?

Comment: @Evgeny, Felt too short for an answer. If the OP comes back and asks, then I will flesh it out and include an example of my code.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz  That's sufficient enough for me to make things work! Thanks a lot!